# Recovery partition for identical OS

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, efi, recovery-partition

I have a recovery partition installed and would like the ability to choose which OS to use the recovery for. There are 2 copies of Windows 10 installed and one copy is a duplicate of the other. I was hoping there was some way to choose which to use the recovery partition for when I decide to use it.

Or do I need to duplicate the recovery partition for the second windows?